# How to convert this sql to EJB QL

Tags: ejbql, to-char

The sql query is:

```
SELECT to_char(DE.DELIVERYID) FROM DELIVERIES DE;
```

`DELIVERYID` in oracle is a number and `deliveryid` in JPA is a `Long`.

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved it!
I have created this field sdeliveryid into delivery entitity:

```
@Column(name="deliveryid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public String getSdeliveryid() {
    if(deliveryid!=null)
        return deliveryid.toString();
    else
        return "";
}


public void setSdeliveryid(String sdeliveryid) {
    this.sdeliveryid = sdeliveryid;
}
```

And I change the EJB QL query like this:

```
SELECT de.sdeliveryid FROM delivery de
```